# jquery toggle open and close 2 div

Tags: jquery

I have the following code to open and close two separate div's which works fine. However what I am trying to achieve is this if one dive is open and i click to open the other one the one that is open closes and visa versa. can someone point me in the right direction.

```
      $(document).ready(function(e) { 
       var menuopen = false;
        $("#searching").click(function(e) {
      if (menuopen == false) {
        $("#search").animate({
         top: "111px"
          }, 1000)
    menuopen = true;
   }
    else if (menuopen == true) {
     $("#search").animate({
    top: "-110px"
    }, 1000)
   menuopen = false
  }
 });
  $("#navigation").click(function(e) {
   if (menuopen == false) {
  $("#menu").animate({
    top: "111px"
  }, 1000)
  menuopen = true;
  }
   else if (menuopen == true) {
     $("#menu").animate({
       top: "-410px"
     }, 1000)
     menuopen = false
   }
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you include `html` at Question? Have you tried calling `.click()` on corresponding element?

Comment: You mean something like this? http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion

Comment: no i have not could you explain

Comment: as @maraca says - use a bootstrap accordion - this is exactly what it does!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a concept how it works, also for double-clicks etc.:

1. Before you call animate you set a flag which indicates that an animation is ongoing.
2. If this flag is set you return immediately and don't call animate.
3. Add a callback function (e.g. complete) to the animate call which resets the flag, so that the menu becomes responsible again.
4. Track the states of the menues somehow (variable or class indicating the state when required anyway for styling), so that you know which one has to be closed or opened.

So you could create a function `menuSelected` and call it from all menu click functions.

You could just toggle on each click and when one menu is clicked fire a click on the other one too, but that's dangerous, e.g. if you do several clicks at once the events could stack up and you will watch the menu open and close several times.

Answer (score 0):

You want to «toggle» two working animations...

Based on this, you could try:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#searching").click(function(e) {
        searchOpen(true);
        menuOpen(false);
    });
    $("#navigation").click(function(e) {
        searchOpen(false);
        menuOpen(true);
    });
});

function searchOpen(logic){
    if (logic) {
        $("#search").animate({
            top: "111px"
        }, 1000)
    }
    else {
        $("#search").animate({
            top: "-110px"
        }, 1000)
    }
}

function menuOpen(logic){
    if (logic) {
        $("#menu").animate({
            top: "111px"
        }, 1000)
    }
    else {
        $("#menu").animate({
            top: "-410px"
        }, 1000)
    }
}
```